# .NET MAUI Display icon in menu bar item in mac catalyst

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I want to show check icon before  items text of menu bar depending on which menu is selected. Default icon is not supported in mac catalyst as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar). Is there any workaround or solution to this?

Since I don't have much knowledge about .Net MAUI, I have tried only builtin menu bar item.

Comment: There is no way can do that. The icon can be added in the menu when it be created in the ios. Because the native view's property can't be set.